# Is it possible to host two wordpress blogs on the same EC2 instance and use different domains to reach them?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, a-records

I have installed and configured two WordPress on my Ubuntu EC2 Instance.
I want to reach them using different domains. So far, I have been able to put an A Record on the domain which shows the page at 52.38.19.133.

The blogs are at 52.38.19.133/Arvind & 52.38.19.133/Shashank. I want to use two different domains to reach them respctively but I am unable to do that either from Domain Registrar's(GoDaddy, in my case) side or from Amazon Route 53 settings.

I don't know if it is understandable what I mentioned up here so I am giving the below example:
When a person visits iamarvindlakhani.com, they should see the page at 52.38.19.133/Arvind .
And a diferent domain, e.g. xyz.com, they should see 52.38.19.133/Shashank .

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two virtual hosts for domains on your apache/Nginx config.

Then point your domains to the IP of your EC2 by A record on DNS domain setting.

Example Virtual Host apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyway, if you finding a page builder for content, you can use the KingComposer https://wordpress.org/plugins/kingcomposer/

Best regards.

Comment: The same approach I was thinking of!